# Delete an already retrieved element with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I already know about `findByIdAndRemove()`, but I want to know if there is a function to delete something Ive already retrieved from the database like `.save()`, heres an example:

```
// Account is our model
const foundAccount = await Account.findById(userId);
// Do something with found account
await foundAccount.[the function to delete this object]();
```

Or if the only way is with `findByIdAndRemove()`:

```
// Account is our model
const foundAccount = await Account.findById(userId);
// Do something with found account
await Account.findByIdAndRemove(foundAccount._id);
```

And last, if there is such a function, does it make any difference in regards to performance with using `findByIdAndRemove()` separately ?

Comment: no its not possible, even if did process would be "exactly" same since in both cases it need to connect database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`deleteOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-deleteOne) or [`remove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove):

```
// Account is our model
const foundAccount = await Account.findById(userId);
// Do something with found account
await foundAccount.deleteOne();
// or
// await foundAccount.remove();
```